# Cómo crear un array de tuplas de diferentes tamaños y que contengan el mismo tipo de datos

Tags: python, numpy, tipos, tuplas, python-3.8

Tengo un array de numpy que en principio desconozco el tamaño, lo creo vacío, y defino el tipo de elementos para que ocupen sólo un byte cada uno.

```
A = np.array([], dtype=np.uint8)
```

después inserto estas tuplas de diferentes tamaños

```
A = np.append(A, [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9, 0)])
print("A:", A.shape, A.nbytes, "bytes", "dtype.name:", A.dtype.name, "\n", A,  "\n")
```

y me da esta salida:

```
A: (3,) 24 bytes dtype.name: object 
[(1, 2, 3) (4, 5) (6, 7, 8, 9, 0)]
```

Esperaba un tamaño de 10 bytes y no 24 bytes. Numpy ha reconvertido la matriz.
Teniendo en cuenta que cada tupla es de diferente tamaño, lo ideal para mi sería algo así:

```
A = np.array([], dtype=[(*all, np.uint8)])
```

donde ***all** sería para todos los campos de cada tupla.

¿Existe algo similar para hacer esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigando y probando, encontré la solución. En este post había algo interesante:
[¿Cómo hacer una matriz numpy multidimensional con un tamaño de fila variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386259/how-to-make-a-multidimension-numpy-array-with-a-varying-row-size)

El ejemplo de FJSevilla estaría bien, si se asignaran los arrays en el momento de la creación de la matriz, numpy los reconoce como objetos array, y funciona bien. Pero cuando se añade con **append** una matriz numpy a la matriz principal, entonces numpy convierte los elementos de este array como elementos individuales del array principal, y no es lo que quiero.

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3])
B = np.array([4, 5])
C = np.array([A, B]) # C: [array([1, 2, 3]) array([4, 5])], En la creación va bien
C = np.append(C, [6, 7, 8]) # [array([1, 2, 3]) array([4, 5]) 6 7 8], pero al añadir esto no
```

Así que la solución es utilizar una combinación de un array nativo de python con arrays de numpy, y después de realizar todos los **appends**, convertir el array de python en array de numpy.

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3]) # Matrices numpy
B = np.array([4, 5]) 
C = [] # Matriz nativa de python
C.append(A) # Insertamos dos elementos (arrays) individuales
C.append(B) # C >> [array([1, 2, 3]) array([4, 5])]
# C.append([A, B]) Así insertamos sólo un elemento con dos matrices, ojo que no 
# es lo mismo, C >> [array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5])] la diferencia está en la 
# coma, se puede usar tambien para crear tuplas, sustituyendo los corchetes, por 
# paréntesis.
```

Después de realizar todos los **appends** convertimos el array.

```
C = np.array(C)
```

Si no hay otra alternativa mejor para gestionar matrices de diferente tamaño, me quedo con esta.
También en más fácil controlar el tipo de los elementos de las matrices, simplemente añadiendo **dtype**

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero, el tamaño que muestra no es lo que ocupan los enteros de las tuplas, es lo que ocupan las referencias en memoria a las propias tuplas que es lo que almacena el array, un array de tipo `object` es un array de referencias sin más.

Los tipos numéricos de NumPy como `uint8` **internamente** no son objetos realmente (instancia de una clase) como lo es `int` en Python, son solo un espacio en memoria de 8 bits (byte) que se interpreta como un entero. Es decir el concepto de tipo es el mismo que en C, no el que tiene Python en el que un tipo equivale a una clase.

NumPy no convierte nada de la tupla, tu tupla es un objeto Python que contiene objetos `int` Python y NumPy se limita a almacenar una referencia a la tupla sin más. Nunca intentará convertir los objetos internos del objeto que almacene, entre otras cosas, la tupla puede almacenar referencias a cualquier cosa.

Un array de NumPy igual que un array en C no puede tener filas de diferente tamaño. No es más que un espacio en memoria contiguo combinado con un patrón de indexado que mapea cada item con una posición en memoria. Por lo tanto el concepto de fila/columna es algo abstracto. Básicamente, en el caso de un array de uin8 de 5x5 cada 8 bytes se considera un nuevo entero y cada 40 una nueva fila o columna (row-major order (C)/column-major order (FORTRAN)) pero los items se almacenan en memoria todos de forma secuencial. Si las filas o columnas tuvieran longitud variable, toda la aritmética de mapeado y de punteros se va al traste y se perdería la eficiencia que implica tener los elementos contiguos en memoria.

Puedes almacenar tuplas que usen la clase `numpy.uint8`:

```
(np.uint(1), np.uint(2), np.uint(3))
```

o usar arrays de NumPy directamente:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([], dtype=np.ndarray)

A = np.append(A, [np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype="uint8"),
                  np.array([4, 5], dtype="uint8"),
                  np.array([6, 7, 8, 9, 0], dtype="uint8")
                 ])

print("A:", A.shape, A.nbytes, "bytes", "dtype.name:", A.dtype.name, "\n", A,  "\n")
```

> A: (3,) 24 bytes dtype.name: object
>     [array([1, 2, 3], dtype=uint8) array([4, 5], dtype=uint8)       array([6, 7, 8, 9, 0], dtype=uint8)]

El array sigue ocupando 24 bytes porque almacena referencias a objetos, tres objetos por 8 bytes cada referencia. No importa el objeto que almacene, una tupla otro array o una lista de 1000000 items, una referencia en Python son 4 bytes en sistemas/intérprete Python de 32 bits y 8 bytes en sistemas/intérprete Python de 64 bits.

En total tendrás tu array de referencias de 24 bytes + 3 arrays o tuplas de 3, 2 y 5 bytes cada uno. En el caso de las tuplas de enteros Python la longitud es variable ya que un entero Python no siempre ocupa los mismos bytes:

> ```
> >>> import sys
>
> >>> sys.getsizeof(5)
> 28
> >>> sys.getsizeof(58558724555)
> 32
> >>> sys.getsizeof(5855875525545555548)
> 36
> >>> sys.getsizeof(5855872455565635365566956333336356699353355365886653553533556886855355565698869)
> 60
> ```

Otra opción más bizarra es usar un [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) de Python con tipo `"b"` o `"B"` en vez de tuplas.

Comment: FJSevilla, muy buena la explicación de cómo Numpy gestiona la memoria, pero lamentablemente tus ejemplos no funcionan muy bien. Con las tuplas he probado así:
A= np.append(A, [np.array((np.uint(1), np.uint(2), np.uint(3)))])
A= np.append(A, [np.array((np.uint(4), np.uint(5)))])
y así:
A= np.append(A, ((np.uint(1), np.uint(2), np.uint(3)))
A= np.append(A, ((np.uint(4), np.uint(5)))

y con los arrays:
A= np.append(A, [np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype="uint8")])
A= np.append(A, [np.array([4, 5], dtype="uint8")])
y me da esta salida en ambos casos:
[1 2 3 4 5] (No hay tuplas)

Comment: Si esto es todo lo que numpy puede hacer con arrays de diferentes tamaños, me decepciona.